# Bilinear Transformation from upper half plane to upper half plane

Tags: complex-analysis

Define $H^+=$ {$z\in \mathbb C: y>0 $}

$H^-$={$z\in \mathbb C: y<0$}

$L^+$={$z\in \mathbb C: x>0$}

$L^-$={$z\in \mathbb C: x<0$}

The function $f(z)=\frac {z}{3z +1}$

1. maps $H^+$ on to $H^+$ and maps $H^-$ on to $H^-$
2. maps $H^+$ on to $H^-$ and maps $H^-$ on to $H^+$
3. maps $H^+$ on to $L^+$ and maps $H^-$ on to $L^-$
4. maps $H^+$ on to $L^-$ and maps $H^-$ on to $l^+$

I know $f(z)=\frac{az+b}{cz+d}$ if $ad-bc>0$ then upper half plane is  mapped to upper half plane and if $ad-bc<0$ then Upper half plane is mapped to Lower half plane. According to Answer sheet option C is right. and I am getting first option right.
Am I right? Thanx for you precious time

Comment: Set $z=x+iy$, use it to express $f(z)$ as a complex number of the form $a + ib$, and then do the case analysis.

Comment: @LuisVera if i take any point from upper half plane and then put in $f(z)$ . from its image can i conclude what will be image of all upper half plane?

Comment: no, but if you look at the general expression I said you could discard the incorrect options, do you know how to put $f(x+iy) = a+ib$?

Comment: what are the real and imaginary parts of $f(z)$?

Comment: ok i tried and write z in terms of w and then compare real and imaginary parts and getting upper half plane get mapped to upper half plane

Comment: with that you can easily find particular points $z_1,z_2,z_3 \in H^+$ such that $f(z_1) \in H^+, f(z_2) \in L^-, f(z_3) \in L^+$ contradicting $2.$, $3.$, and $4.$ respectively.